# Fast way to insert values in column of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently trying to find unique elements between two columns of a data frame and write these to a new final data frame.
This is my code, which works perfectly fine, and creates a result which matches my expectation.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(1:15, 10), 
                 b=sample(1:15, 10))



unique_to_a <-  df$a[!(df$a %in% df$b)]

unique_to_b <- df$b[!(df$b %in% df$a)]




n <- max(c(unique_to_a, unique_to_b))

out <- data.frame(A=rep(NA,n), B=rep(NA,n))

for (element in unique_to_a){
  out[element, "A"] = element
}

for (element in unique_to_b){
  out[element, "B"] = element
}

out
```

The problem is, that it is *very* slow, because the real data contains 100.000s of rows. I am quite sure it is because of the repeated indexing I am doing in the for loop, and I am sure there is a quicker, vectorized way, but I dont see it...

Any ideas on how to speed up the operation is much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: i think there is a typo in your first for loop (calling `element`?).

Comment: If you have a computer with several cores, you might consider to parallelize the execution of your code. See: [R with doParallel package](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/07/lets-be-faster-and-more-parallel-in-r-with-doparallel-package/)

Comment: Your `for` loops are redundant here. Instead of `for (element in unique_to_a) out[element, "A"] = element` You can just do `out[unique_to_a, "A"] <- unique_to_a`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't compare the speed but at least this is more concise:

```
elements <- with(df, list(setdiff(a, b), setdiff(b, a)))
data.frame(sapply(elements, \(x) replace(rep(NA, max(unlist(elements))), x, x)))
#    X1 X2
# 1  NA NA
# 2  NA NA
# 3  NA  3
# 4  NA NA
# 5  NA NA
# 6  NA NA
# 7  NA NA
# 8  NA NA
# 9  NA NA
# 10 NA NA
# 11 11 NA
```